# Drag activity like notification android

Tags: android, android-activity, drag-and-drop

I have 2 activities, I want to drag one activity above the other without loosing the information of the first activity, like the notification, you are on the internet, you drag the notification, see something, then you drag the notifications back and continious to do what you were doing.

How do I do that, or what should I search for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Any activity can be made modal by configuring it as a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect what youre looking is a [SlidingDrawer.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html)

As the doc says,

> SlidingDrawer hides content out of the screen and allows the user to drag a handle to bring the content on screen. SlidingDrawer can be used vertically or horizontally.

Comment: That is exactly what I want, thanks for your help, now I have something to looking for.